# Multiple div append and select with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have created multiple div boxes (under planning) using javascript [here](http://www.dunlark.com/1francois/)

```
for (i = 0; i < 168; i++) {
    var iDiv = document.createElement('div');
    iDiv.id = 'inc';
    document.getElementById('appointmentchart').appendChild(iDiv);
}
```

**Now I need 2 more things to be done using JavaScript.**

1. On click inside any `div` inside planning assign `class="yellow"` to 3 consecutive `div` vertically (now the `div`s are arranged horizontally).

   Do I need to arrange div vertically for doing this? If so, how?
2. Go to `Practicien` at left side, select `Chirurgie` -> `DUPONT Marc` and then select date `10-Mar-2014`. You will see appointments visible at the Multiple planning `div` chart. Some of them come out of the container.

   How to move the overflowing section to the next `div`?

Is it possible to achieve the above-mentioned using JavaScript?

Comment: you are repeating the id in for loop, change it to something like `iDiv.id= 'inc'+i`

Comment: define `next div`. div to the right? it seems length for 2 div is overflowing, and only 1 div is there to the right of overflowing div at bottom left..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first of all give different id's to the columns as follows:

```
for (i = 0; i < 168; i++) {
var iDiv = document.createElement('div');
iDiv.id = 'inc'+i; //different id
iDiv.addEventListener('click', clickFunction);// assign click handler
document.getElementById('appointmentchart').appendChild(iDiv);
}
```

assuming each row will always have 14 columns you can do

```
function clickFunction(){
 var num= parseInt(this.id.substring(3));
 for(var i=1;i<=3;i++){
  document.getElementById('inc'+num).className+= 'yellow'
  num+=14;
 }
}
```

**Update :**  [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/Gayr4/)

Comment: i get the following error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'substring' of undefined

Comment: @Sparkz change `clickFunction()` to `clickFunction` to avoid the error.. check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/Gayr4/ , its working fine

Answer (score 0):

the answer to your question 1) is:

Consecutive elements are judged by the order they appear in your HTML code, not based on where they end up on the screen. If your planning grid stays the same shape, always having the same number of divs in a row and column, it is pretty easy to get the ones you want.

```
var clickedDiv=//point this at the div you clicked on
//select the grid squares
var divs=document.getElementById('appointmentchart').getElementsByTagName('div');
//how many divs across your grid is
var cols=14; 

 for(var i=0;i<divs.length;i++){
  //find the clicked divs index
  if(clickedDiv=divs[i]){
    //make next three yellow
    for(var y=1;y<4;y++){
          var sqaure=cols*y;
          if(i+square<divs.length){
             divs[i+square].className='yellow';
          }
     }
    break;
 }
}
```